# Plain Text for LaTeX, No Rich Text Features

Tags: filetype-tex

[image: Screenshot_20201114_191025]

Look at Line 37 and Line 45, Line 45 has been folded so that `$...$` does not show. But I do not want this feature. Is there any way to stop it? (I have not installed vimtex)

Also I do not want the rich text symbols:

[image: Screenshot_20201114_191358]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `:h latex-syntax`, specifically `:h tex-conceal`

```
 Tex: Taking Advantage of Conceal Mode~

If you have |'conceallevel'| set to 2 and if your encoding is utf-8, then a
number of character sequences can be translated into appropriate utf-8 glyphs,
including various accented characters, Greek characters in MathZones, and
superscripts and subscripts in MathZones.  Not all characters can be made into
superscripts or subscripts; the constraint is due to what utf-8 supports.
In fact, only a few characters are supported as subscripts.
```

Make sure you have `conceallevel` equal to `0`, if not, check where it is redefined with `verbose set conceallevel?` and do appropriate change to your config.

Comment: Thanks, I added:`let g:tex_conceal=""`